# How do I load multiple URLs with a function using urllib?

Tags: python

I want to do something like this:

```
def load(*args):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(args)
load("url...", "local...")
```

I'm not that familiar with Python, so I'm not sure how to do it or even if `*args` is being used correctly.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? What is this for?

Comment: You can't pass a list of URLs to `urllib.request.urlretrieve` (see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)). You might need to use a loop.